# How force ID generator for class "indentity" to increment for last inserted Id in SQL

Tags: sql, hibernate

I want ask for some advice about,why my `<generator class="identity" />` generate id in table not as as last inserted + 1 but like e.g last insert ID is 5, and when save record then a new Id has be for example 7, so ID value 6 is skipped

(i need use **identity** not **increment** class due to advantage of  this "identity" class for my mySql database)

because in my case i need  same ID value for primary key and foreign key, must be equals,,but in this case i got Primary key 7 and Foreign key will generate also but not  as incremented by last ID,

both class has Hibernate mappings, with this `<generator class="identity" />` 
What i must use so that to obtain both incremented ID with new record by "identity"?

Comment: Foreign keys should be set to the value of the primary key. They should not be generated independently and the primary key should certainly not depend on the value of the foreign key. This is very very odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your table with a primary key using "AUTO_INCREMENT" such as :

`CREATE TABLE person (
     id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
)`

Then your GenerationType.IDENTITY must do the job.

Comment: hm i check my tables,both has these auto_increment, but i noticed when i use this GenerationType.IDENTITY, my last ID is e.g 7 and new Id will generate as for example 9(so not increment and skip ID value 8) then i delete this ID,and when again save new ID,so new ID will be value 10, so increment is working but not continue form last insert ID (from 7)